# Typescript Redux - Typing of initialState with CreateSlice

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have used CreateSlice to create my reducer/actions like in the code below:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Modal } from 'antd';

export interface ModalState {
  modalProps: React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal>;
  visible: boolean;
  modalContent: string;
}

export interface ModalInfos {
  modalProps: React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal>;
  modalContent: string;
}

const initialState = {
  modalProps: {},
  visible: false,
  modalContent: '',
};

const modal = createSlice({
  name: 'modal',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    openModal(state, action: PayloadAction<ModalInfos>) {
      state.modalProps = action.payload.modalProps;
      state.modalContent = action.payload.modalContent;
      state.visible = true;
    },
    closeModal(state) {
      state.visible = false;
    },
  },
});

export const { openModal, closeModal } = modal.actions;

export default modal.reducer;
```

I did not type my initialstate (so I am not using my ModalState interface), but when I try to do that:

```
const initialState: ModalState = {
  modalProps: {},
  visible: false,
  modalContent: '',
};
```

I then get a strange error message on the following line:

```
state.modalProps = action.payload.modalProps;
```

The message is:

```
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<ModalProps>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<PropsWithChildren<ModalProps>>'.
  Types of property 'okButtonProps' are incompatible.
    Type 'Partial<{ href: string; target?: string | undefined; onClick?: ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; } & BaseButtonProps & Pick<...> & { ...; } & Pick<...>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Partial<{ href: string; target?: string | undefined; onClick?: ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; } & BaseButtonProps & Pick<...> & { ...; } & Pick<...>>> | undefined'.
      Type 'Partial<{ href: string; target?: string | undefined; onClick?: ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; } & BaseButtonProps & Pick<...> & { ...; } & Pick<...>>' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Partial<{ href: string; target?: string | undefined; onClick?: ((event: MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined; } & BaseButtonProps & Pick<...> & { ...; } & Pick<...>>>'.
        Types of property 'defaultValue' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | number | readonly string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
            Type 'readonly string[]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'.
              The type 'readonly string[]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
```

Is it OK not to assign a type to my initalState ? If not, the types of "state.modalProps" and "action.payload.modalProps" are in my opinion identical, so I am not sure how to fix that...

Comment: please add 'antd' tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

No, you *must* declare a type for your `initialState`.  That's how `createSlice` interprets the actual type of `state` for the rest of the reducers.  You need:

```
const initialState : ModalState = {
  modalProps: {},
  visible: false,
  modalContent: '',
};
```

There's nothing wrong with defining two different interfaces here.  That said, if you *really* want to avoid having to define the two common fields twice, you can either do:

```
export interface ModalInfos {
  modalProps: React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal>;
  modalContent: string;
}
export interface ModalState extends ModalInfos {
  visible: boolean;
}
```

or:

```
export interface ModalState {
  modalProps: React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal>;
  visible: boolean;
  modalContent: string;
}

export type ModalInfos = Omit<ModalState, 'visible'>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it means that I really have a problem as I get an error message in my action. I tried defining the two interfaces like you suggested, but my error message is still there. It seem to be specifically related to the type "React.ComponentProps<typeof Modal>"

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for partially updating modal props:

```
// replace
// state.modalProps = action.payload.modalProps;
// with
state.modalProps = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, state.modalProps), action.payload.modalProps);
```

OR

```
import { ModalProps } from 'antd/lib/modal';
import { CaseReducer, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

type State = ModalProps;

const initialState: State = {
  visible: false
}

const reducers: {
  updateModal: CaseReducer<State, PayloadAction<ModalProps>
} = {
  updateModal(state, action) {
    return Object.assign(Object.assign({}, state), action.payload);
  }
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'modal',
  initialState,
  reducers
});

export { updateModal } = slice.actions;

// in some React component
dispatch(updateModal({ onOk: () => { /* do something */ } }));
```